# How to close admob inersitial after click on it

Tags: android, admob, interstitial

I use AdMob Interstitials in my Android app in a simple way, just something like in example from

https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/admob/advanced?hl=no-NO&csw=1#android

This code works correct. But there is one extra thing I wanna do - close AdMob banner after user clicks it. I mean, when user comes back to my app from page opened with click, there is still AdMob banner on screen, but I wanna see my app's screen.

I do not see the close method or something about it in the class InterstitialAd.

Is there simple way to solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to do this.
The user must close the Interstitial.

Answer (score -1):

By keeping
onHistory="true" for activity android:name="com.google.ads.AdActivity" in manifest worked for me.